# OpenSSL PKCS#11 signing multi process

Tags: c++, openssl, segmentation-fault, pkcs#11

I'm debugging a segmentation fault in a php module written by someone for an application (so changing the workflow and other time consuming operations are out of the question).

I have the following code:
...

`...some code...
int marker=0;
ENGINE_load_dynamic();
ENGINE *e=ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");
if (e==NULL) return NULL;
...some more code to set some parameters using ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(...)`

`marker++; // gets about 10 or something
e=ENGINE_by_id("pkcs11");
if (e==NULL) return NULL;`

Here comes the fun part - SIGSEGV:

`marker++; //11
if (!ENGINE_init(e)){
std::cout<<"..error..";
ENGINE_finish(e);
ENGINE_free(e);
ENGINE_cleanup();
return null;
}`

`...code using pkcs#11 token that does work....`

The problem appears in a random manner, sort of. The snippet is part of a php module. The script is called from a PostgreSQL script which in turn is called by another php application residing on another server (don't blame me for this design, I'm here to debug). The SIGSEGV appears when I refresh the main php application page quickly, which I assume it calls the above scripts multiple times concurrently, therefore attempting to use the token from separate processes at the same time.

Are my assumptions correct? can calls to ENGINE_init/finish/free from separate processes using the same token collide and cause a segmentation fault?

The segmentation fault is captured using my handler that picks up the marker value and prints it before exit, it's the simplest method I could come up for sigsegv debug. If this method might yield wrong results I'd appreciate the notification.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "which I assume it calls the above scripts multiple times concurrently, therefore attempting to use the token from separate processes at the same time." - OpenSSL is not thread safe by default. Are the static locks installed?

Answer (score 0):

There's a *README.ENGINE* that provides a discussion of engines. I'm not sure how useful it will be since it makes some tall claims. For example, "... the source code is reasonably well self-documenting, but some summaries and usage instructions are needed".

But here's something on the `dynamic`:

> The new "dynamic" ENGINE provides a low-overhead way to support
>   ENGINE   implementations that aren't pre-compiled and linked into
>   OpenSSL-based   applications. This could be because existing
>   compiled-in implementations   have known problems and you wish to use
>   a newer version with an existing   application. It could equally be
>   because the application (or OpenSSL   library) you are using simply
>   doesn't have support for the ENGINE you   wish to use, and the ENGINE
>   provider (eg. hardware vendor) is providing   you with a
>   self-contained implementation in the form of a shared-library.   The
>   other use-case for "dynamic" is with applications that wish to
>   maintain the smallest foot-print possible and so do not link in
>   various   ENGINE implementations from OpenSSL, but instead leaves you
>   to provide   them, if you want them, in the form of "dynamic"-loadable
>   shared-libraries. It should be possible for hardware vendors to
>   provide   their own shared-libraries to support arbitrary hardware to
>   work with   applications based on OpenSSL 0.9.7 or later. If you're
>   using an   application based on 0.9.7 (or later) and the support you
>   desire is only   announced for versions later than the one you need,
>   ask the vendor to   backport their ENGINE to the version you need.
>
> How does "dynamic" work?
>
> ```
> The dynamic ENGINE has a special flag in its implementation such that
> every time application code asks for the 'dynamic' ENGINE, it in fact
> gets its own copy of it. As such, multi-threaded code (or code that
> multiplexes multiple uses of 'dynamic' in a single application in any
> way at all) does not get confused by 'dynamic' being used to do many
> independent things. Other ENGINEs typically don't do this so there is
> only ever 1 ENGINE structure of its type (and reference counts are used
> to keep order). The dynamic ENGINE itself provides absolutely no
> cryptographic functionality, and any attempt to "initialise" the ENGINE
> automatically fails. All it does provide are a few "control commands"
> that can be used to control how it will load an external ENGINE
> implementation from a shared-library. To see these control commands,
> use the command-line;
>
>    openssl engine -vvvv dynamic
>
> The "SO_PATH" control command should be used to identify the
> shared-library that contains the ENGINE implementation, and "NO_VCHECK"
> might possibly be useful if there is a minor version conflict and you
> (or a vendor helpdesk) is convinced you can safely ignore it.
> "ID" is probably only needed if a shared-library implements
> multiple ENGINEs, but if you know the engine id you expect to be using,
> it doesn't hurt to specify it (and this provides a sanity check if
> nothing else). "LIST_ADD" is only required if you actually wish the
> loaded ENGINE to be discoverable by application code later on using the
> ENGINE's "id". For most applications, this isn't necessary - but some
> application authors may have nifty reasons for using it. The "LOAD"
> command is the only one that takes no parameters and is the command
> that uses the settings from any previous commands to actually *load*
> the shared-library ENGINE implementation. If this command succeeds, the
> (copy of the) 'dynamic' ENGINE will magically morph into the ENGINE
> that has been loaded from the shared-library. As such, any control
> commands supported by the loaded ENGINE could then be executed as per
> normal. Eg. if ENGINE "foo" is implemented in the shared-library
> "libfoo.so" and it supports some special control command "CMD_FOO", the
> following code would load and use it (NB: obviously this code has no
> error checking);
>
>    ENGINE *e = ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");
>    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "SO_PATH", "/lib/libfoo.so", 0);
>    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "ID", "foo", 0);
>    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "LOAD", NULL, 0);
>    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(e, "CMD_FOO", "some input data", 0);
>
> For testing, the "openssl engine" utility can be useful for this sort
> of thing. For example the above code excerpt would achieve much the
> same result as;
>
>    openssl engine dynamic \
>              -pre SO_PATH:/lib/libfoo.so \
>              -pre ID:foo \
>              -pre LOAD \
>              -pre "CMD_FOO:some input data"
>
> Or to simply see the list of commands supported by the "foo" ENGINE;
>
>    openssl engine -vvvv dynamic \
>              -pre SO_PATH:/lib/libfoo.so \
>              -pre ID:foo \
>              -pre LOAD
>
> Applications that support the ENGINE API and more specifically, the
> "control commands" mechanism, will provide some way for you to pass
> such commands through to ENGINEs. As such, you would select "dynamic"
> as the ENGINE to use, and the parameters/commands you pass would
> control the *actual* ENGINE used. Each command is actually a name-value
> pair and the value can sometimes be omitted (eg. the "LOAD" command).
> Whilst the syntax demonstrated in "openssl engine" uses a colon to
> separate the command name from the value, applications may provide
> their own syntax for making that separation (eg. a win32 registry
> key-value pair may be used by some applications). The reason for the
> "-pre" syntax in the "openssl engine" utility is that some commands
> might be issued to an ENGINE *after* it has been initialised for use.
> Eg. if an ENGINE implementation requires a smart-card to be inserted
> during initialisation (or a PIN to be typed, or whatever), there may be
> a control command you can issue afterwards to "forget" the smart-card
> so that additional initialisation is no longer possible. In
> applications such as web-servers, where potentially volatile code may
> run on the same host system, this may provide some arguable security
> value. In such a case, the command would be passed to the ENGINE after
> it has been initialised for use, and so the "-post" switch would be
> used instead. Applications may provide a different syntax for
> supporting this distinction, and some may simply not provide it at all
> ("-pre" is almost always what you're after, in reality).
> ```